# Angular JS $timeout and $scope function communication

Tags: javascript, angularjs, web, angularjs-scope, timeout

I just find strange(for me) thing in angularjs. Why do these parts work differently?

**Timeout is Working (alert after 8sec)**

```
$scope.testfun = function(){
    alert(2);
}
$scope.activate = function(h,m,s){
    if(h != 0 || m != 0 || s != 0) $timeout($scope.testfun, 8000);
}
```

**Timeout is NOT Working (alert momentally)**

```
$scope.testfun = function(){
    alert(2);
}
$scope.activate = function(h,m,s){
    if(h != 0 || m != 0 || s != 0) $timeout($scope.testfun(), 8000);
}
```

Difference in $scope.testfun and $scope.testfun()

Comment: In the first case you delay (pass into `$timeout`) the function; in the second, the result of _calling_ this function.

Comment: How can I delay the second variant? If I need to send parameters I will need testfun(param). But in this case there will be no delay

Comment: Either use .bind/_.partial, or create another function manually: `$timeout(function() { $scope.testfun(someParam); }, 8000)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to write timeout function like below::

```
$scope.testfun = function() {
    alert(2);
}

$scope.activate = function(h,m,s) {
    if (h != 0 || m != 0 || s != 0) {
      $timeout(function () {
        $scope.testfun();
      }, 8000);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For `$scope.function()` is wrong.

```
$timeout(function() { $scope.testfun(someParam); }, 8000)
```

The scope is the binding part between the HTML (view) and the JavaScript (controller).

The scope is an object with the available properties and methods.

The scope is available for both the view and the controller.